# PrimeNG: Differnce between p-Table and p-dataTable

Tags: angular, primeng

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

As per the above link in the latest version of PrimeNG `p-dataTable` is deprecated.

I have implemented my tables using version 5.2.7.

Does it mean I have changed all the implementation? I have made for `p-dataTable` to `p-table` to use all new feature available for the table?

What is the best way to upgrade my table implementation?

And if I don't do that then will the latest version of PrimeNG will support for `p-dataTable`?

Answer (score 16):

`p-table` which is also known as *TurboTable*, we can say it is advanced version of `p-dataTable`. PrimeNG team highly improved. As per the documentation `p-dataTable` can render 5000 rows of 8 columns in 10 seconds whereas *TurboTable* does it in less than **0.5 seconds**.

> Does it mean i have change all the implementation i have made for
>   p-dataTable to p-table to use all new feature available for table?

For the performance improvement they have created all new `p-table` component. So If you want to achieve all new feature you will have change your implementation. Some more details here [PrimeNG Turbo Table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5-2-0-rc1-released-turbotable/)

> What is the best way to upgrade my table implementation?
>
> And if i don't do that than will the latest version of PrimeNG will
>   support for p-dataTable?

For upgrading table component you need to follow the documentation. That is the only way to upgrade.
Most probably latest version of PrimeNG will not support `p-dataTable`. You can see the last comment at this link : [TurboTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5-2-0-rc1-released-turbotable). They clearly mentioned:
*It is deprecated and will be removed in a future release so that we can focus on improving TurboTable.*

For more details you can see the thread at [Github](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4743)