# PrimeNG datatable performance very slow in case there is a lot of data

Tags: performance, primeng, primeng-datatable

I use PrimeNG datatable. In case the table contains many rows, the datatable's performance works very slow.
This is my html:

```
  <p-dataTable #dt  [rowTrackBy]="rowTrackBy" [emptyMessage]="'TABLE.EMPTY_MESSAGE'|translate" #dt [rows]="rows" [paginator]="paginator"
       lazy="false" [pageLinks]="3" scrollable="true"[editable]="editable" [styleClass]="paginator?'paginator': enableFilter?'scroll filter-table':'scroll'"
        [globalFilter]="gb"[value]="displayList" resizableColumns="true" [(selection)]="selectedItem"
        (onRowDblclick)="importButton?'':onRowDblclick($event.data)"[expandableRows]="showExpander" [expandedRows]="expandedRows"
        (onRowSelect)="onrowSelect($event)" (onRowClick)="selectRow($event);onrowSelect($event)" (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnSelect($event)"[rowStyleClass]="rowStyleClass"
        [selectionMode]="(enableSelect&&!showSelectColumn)?(multiSelect?'multiple':'single'):''" [metaKeySelection]="false"
        (onHeaderCheckboxToggle)="onHeaderCheckboxToggle($event)">
```

Comment: Which version of PrimeNG do you use ?

Comment: My primeNG version is: 6.1.6

Comment: Datatable is deprecated and you should use Turbotable instead which is available in PrimeNG 6.1.6 : turbotable is at least 10x faster than datatable.

Comment: If you are using Version 6 use `<p-table>` which is also know as turbotable and this is very fast. Fo more detail check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52983328/primeng-differnce-between-p-table-and-p-datatable/52984839#52984839)